# router.navigate with query params Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm having an issue with routing to a route with query params I have a function like so

```
goToLink(link) {
    this.router.navigate([`${link.split('?')[0]}`, { queryParams: this.sortParams(link)}]);
}
```

and this function

```
sortParams(link) {
    let queryParams = url.split('?')[1];
    let params = queryParams.split('&');
    let pair = null;
    let data = {};
    params.forEach((d) => {
      pair = d.split('=');
      data[`${pair[0]}`] = pair[1];
    });
    return data;
}
```

okay so basically what Is happening I have a function called `goToLink()` and that takes in a url and the url that gets passed is a string with query params like so..

`https://website.com/page?id=37&username=jimmy`

the above is just an example thats not what it actually looks like but its a link string with query parameters now so what happens is I remove the params from the string and store them in a data object in the `sortParams()` function so when I pass the above string in I get an object that looks like this

`{id: 37, username: 'jimmy'}`

now thats what i'm passing into the `queryParams:` section in the router.navigate,

the function should look like this when the object is returned

```
this.router.navigate([`${link.split('?')[0]}`, { queryParams: {id: 37, username: 'jimmy'}}]);
```

so i successfully route to the desired route but the query params look like this..

`/page;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Am I doing something wrong here??

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

If I just change the function to this

```
 this.router.navigate([`${link.split('?')[0]}`, { queryParams: {id: 37, username: 'jimmy'}}]);
```

I get the same url `/page;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Comment: take a look at this https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Can be of that you had placed the bracket which is supposedly for the 1st param but you had encapsulated it on the whole line of route

**Your code:**

```
// This is the end of your route statement:  '}}]);' which the close bracket is included
this.router.navigate([`${link.split('?')[0]}`, { queryParams: {id: 37, username: 'jimmy'}}]);
```

**Update route:**

place the **]** close bracket within the 1st parameter only, try to not place it on the last part of the route statement.

```
// Update end line: '}});'
this.router.navigate([`${link.split('?')[0]}`], { queryParams: {id: 37, username: 'jimmy'}});
```

---

**Summary:**

```
this.router.navigate([ url ], { queryParams: { ... } })
```

Answer (score 73):

If you want to navigate to a URL string including query params, try using [router.navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl).

For example:

`this.router.navigateByUrl('/page?id=37&username=jimmy');`

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: I also agree that this is the right and simplest solution.
Especially when I get the URL from another source, so in this solution I do not have to deal with it, rather I can use it as it is.

Comment: this works great and you can get the params from ActivatedRoute by subscribing like `activatedRoute.params.subscribe`

Answer (score 27):

Try like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['my-route', 37], { queryParams: { username: "jimmy"}});
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/page?id=37&username=jimmy');
```

This is better when the params are dynamic.