# Angular query params is object object

Tags: angular

I'm trying to navigate including query params:

```
this.router.navigate(['/forum/topic/1', { queryParams: { reply: 5 } }]);
```

But it redirect me to `/forum/topic/1;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Expected behavior:

```
/forum/topic/1?reply=5
```

Looking at the document I see they edit the params because I see it's separate with ;

```
localhost:4200/heroes;id=15;foo=foo
```

What are they doing ?

1) How can I fix the redirection, I think the function is fine...

2) I don't want **;**, I want classic **?** and **&**, is it possible ?

Comment: just use `this.router.navigate(['/forum/topic/1?reply=5']);`? it worked when i tried it in angular 4 i believe, so it should still work in 6 and 7, whichever youre using

Comment: I tryed but I get forum/topic/1%3Freply%3D5

Comment: in which case, its encoding it for some reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass query parameters with a routerLink in the new Router V 3 alpha (vladivostok)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink-in-the-new-router-v-3-alpha-vlad)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [router.navigate with query params Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52980345/1260204)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo. Look at parenthesis.
Try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/forum/topic/1'], { queryParams: { reply: 5 } });
```